# Java Threading, suspending multiple other threads while one is running

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand concurrency for part of an assignment I'm doing.  I think I've got the basics done, but I'm getting stuck in the nuances of my usecase.

I apologize in advance if I haven't mastered the art of the question yet.

Basic idea:

I have a class, of which a few objects are instantiated as representations of parts of a houses and their only main function is to operate().  The catch is that when "Bell" operates, I want the others to wait().  My while statement is based on a bell toggle (boolean).  If it is on - wait(), if not, carry on.   It seems when running this program, I'm starving the other threaded objects for the sake "Bell".

Any thoughts on where I've gone wrong?

```html
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Test extends Thread { 
  static int number = 0;
  private static final int TIMES = 30; 
  private static boolean bellstatus = false;
  private String name;
  private int val; 
 
   Test(String y,int x) { 
    number = number +1;
     val = x;
    name = new String(y);
  } 
  public void run() { // overrides default run() 
   
    for (int i=val; i>0; i--){ 
      System.out.println(name+" run() : " + i);
      operate();
    }
  }
  
  public synchronized void operate(){
   System.out.println(name+ " operating");
  
   while(bellstatus){
     try{
     System.out.println("Bell is ringing");
     wait();}catch(InterruptedException e){}
   }
   
   if(name.equals("Bell")){
     try{
     System.out.println("Bell working");
     bellstatus = true;
     Thread.sleep(500);
     Thread.yield();}catch(InterruptedException e){}
     bellstatus = false;
     notifyAll();
     System.err.println("Bell is done");
 }
   
   if(name.equals("Door")){
     try{
     System.out.println("Door working");
     Thread.sleep(500);}catch(InterruptedException e){}
   }
   if(name.equals("Window")){
     try{
     System.out.println("Window working");
     Thread.sleep(500);}catch(InterruptedException e){}
  }
  }     
  

  
  
public static void main(String arg[]) { 
   ArrayList<Test> example = new ArrayList();
    Test a = new Test("Bell",20);
    Test b = new Test("Door",20);
    Test c = new Test("Window",20);// create thread 
    
    example.add(a);
    example.add(b);
    example.add(c);
    
    System.out.println("Number of objects: "+a.number);
    for(int i = 0;i<example.size();i++)
      example.get(i).start();
    
    
                             // start thread run 
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use just one thread and a queue of runnables.  An executor with just one thread will queue your tasks until the one running  is done https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Comment: Hi, Thank you for taking a look at this.  I'm trying to make it such that Bell stops all the other objects from running - I'm not sure a queue is what I want?  In any case, the two other approaches that have been advised are within the scope of the course I am taking - so I think I'll scratch away along those lines.  Thanks again for taking the time to look.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use [Raw Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) (you could use the diamond operator `<>`). Then, if I understand your question, one possible solution is to use a [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) like,

```
static class Test extends Thread {
    static int number = 0;

    private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private String name;
    private int val;

    Test(String y, int x) {
        number = number + 1;
        val = x;
        name = new String(y);
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = val; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(name + " run() : " + i);
            operate();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void operate() {
        System.out.printf("%s operating%n", name);
        lock.lock();
        try {
            System.out.printf("%s working%n", name);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.printf("%s done%n", name);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String arg[]) {
    List<Test> example = new ArrayList<>();
    Test a = new Test("Bell", 20);
    Test b = new Test("Door", 20);
    Test c = new Test("Window", 20);// create thread

    example.add(a);
    example.add(b);
    example.add(c);

    System.out.println("Number of objects: " + a.number);
    for (int i = 0; i < example.size(); i++) {
        example.get(i).start();
    }
    // start thread run
}
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to Raw Types - I'm taking a crash course in Java - so I don't know what I'm missing.  Thanks for taking a look at my code.  I've been following the java tutorials on Oracle and have a general idea of ReEntrant Lock works.  My problem is trying to figure out how I can make it such that "Bell" is the only one that can call lock/unlock - when Bell runs operate, now other object can.  This property only applies to Bell. Again, thanks for taking a look - I'll be reading up some more.

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc of `notifyAll` mentions:

> Wakes up all threads that are waiting on this object's monitor. A thread waits on an object's monitor by calling one of the wait methods.

However the `operate` method is synchronizing on the instance of the thread object. Hence `notifyAll` will not wake up the threads that are waiting, *since each thread owns a different monitor and is waiting on that monitor*.

One way to solve this is by synchronizing on a shared lock:

```
...
static Object lock = new Object();
...

public void operate() {
    synchronized (lock) {

        System.out.println(name + " operating");

        while (bellstatus) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Bell is ringing");
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        if (name.equals("Bell")) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Bell working");
                bellstatus = true;
                Thread.sleep(500);
                Thread.yield();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            bellstatus = false;
            lock.notifyAll();
            System.err.println("Bell is done");
        }

        if (name.equals("Door")) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Door working");
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        if (name.equals("Window")) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Window working");
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking a look at this.  I've tried this method as outlined in my course textbook.  My countdown is successful, yet I'm not sure that it is working correctly as the statement "Bell is ringing" never shows up. I've played with Bell's sleep setting, setting it longer while making the others shorter to no avail. I'm wondering what is a valid way of testing that this works.  Thanks again.